# can't connect scrapy to my database

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I had to do a crawler and put the data in a DB.
I already collect my data, but i have problem to put them in the DB.

My files are:

topcrawlerspider.py (my crawler, he is fonctional):

```
from scrapy import Spider, Item, Field, Request
from ..items import TopcrawlerItem
from ..pipelines import TopcrawlerPipeline
import time

class TopSpider(Spider):

name = 'topcrawler'
start_urls = ['...']

def __init__(self, page=0, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TopSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.search_result_url_tpl = 'http://.../%s'
...
```

settings.py :

```
BOT_NAME = 'topcrawler'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['topcrawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'topcrawler.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the 
user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'topcrawler (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
 'topcrawler.pipelines.TopcrawlerPipeline': 300,
 # 'topcrawler.pipelines.JsonWriterPipeline': 800,
}

MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889/mtdbdd'
MONGO_DATABASE = 'mtdbdd'
```

pipelines.py :

```
import pymongo
from settings import *

class TopcrawlerPipeline(object):

 collection_name = 'land'

def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
    self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
    self.mongo_db = mongo_db

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(
        mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
        mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
    )

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
    self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.client.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
    return item
```

and i have the error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

it seem's it don't connect to the port 8889 like i want but i don't undertand why ...

Thanks for ure help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TopcrawlerPipeline` class and method `open_spider` (in `pipelines.py` file), you have duplicated `client` creation:

```
self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(connect=False)
self.client = 
    pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889/mtdbdd')
```

I bet the error comes from the first one (which I assume is unintentional). Delete the first one and leave only the second one.

Just a sidenote, to reason where the error might come from. If you don't specify connection string in `MongoClient`, it tries to connect to localhost and default port of 27017. Check your `/etc/hosts` file for how localhost is defined (I assume you are on Linux). On some systems, only IPv6 address is assigned for localhost and MongoDB by default doesn't listen on IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Hi ! thanks for answer.

i edit my file pipeline.py (like i edit in the post) but i have again the same error :/

Comment: In your `pipelines.py` you use `MONGO_URI` but in `settings.py` you define  `MONGODB_URI`. That's probably the source of error. Check it out please.